# Is a test double programmed to throw exception still a "stub"?

Tags: mocking, mockito, xunit, stub, test-double

Arguing with my colleague on terminology.

Imagine the following jUnit test:

```java
class PlanetDensityCalculatorTest {
    PlanetService planetServiceTestDouble = Mockito.mock(PlanetService.class);

    PlanetDensityCalculator calculator = new PlanetDensityCalculator(planetServiceTestDouble);

    @Test
    void shouldReturnDensityForCorrectPlanet() throws InvalidPlanetException {
        Mockito.when(planetServiceTestDouble.findPlanet("Some Planet")).thenReturn(
                new SomePlanet("Some Planet", 639, 3389, 226)
        );
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnNegativeDensityForIncorrectPlanet() throws InvalidPlanetException {
        Mockito.when(planetServiceTestDouble.findPlanet("incorrect planet")).thenThrow(new InvalidPlanetException(""));
        // ...
    }
}
```

I call `planetServiceTestDouble` a "stub". It just return some hard-coded result (either return-value or throws hard-coded exception).

My colleague says:

> It's **mock**, because you specify not only the returned value, but it also has some programmed behaviour, like throwing an exception under certain conditions.

I do not agree with him, because:

1. even though `planetServiceTestDouble` can behave differently on different input, it's still a **stub**, because it returns hard-coded values with no logic (besides the input value).
2. It can't be called a **mock**, because we do not `verify` interaction with this test double (which is IMO an essential thing in test double to be called a mock)

PS: looks like there can be a mismatch in test doubles terminology, but I am looking for answer in the context of Martin Fowler/xUnit test patterns definitions.

Comment: An exception is just a "special return value". I think arguing about terminology is opinion-based at best (and why does it matter? call it a "test double" and move on)

Comment: @knittl agree on a special return value, still a stub. I think it's worth to know the difference if there is even an article by Martin Fowler https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html . My understanding is that the key difference is: do you want to verify outgoing interaction or not? For this purpose you need to distinguish them and not to 1) create over-specification for stub 2) or forget to verify interaction wtih a mock